# How do I import many textures from an OBJ file?

Tags: obj

I am importing a Minecraft world's area from Mineways and its given me both an OBJ and an MTL, but the MTL, when imported from Import OBJ, doesn't change any textures. Is there a way to mass texture an OBJ very easily? I have a beefy computer, so resources are no problem.

[image: Image of current project status]

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the obj and mtl file. In general it should work out of the box if the obj and mtl files are properly formatted: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531